# Access AKKA mailbox object in Actor

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using a custom mailbox with my Akka actor. My class looks something like this:

```
MyActor extends Actor with RequiresMessageQueue[DRMailbox]{ ... }
```

How can I access the `DRMailbox` object in Akka actor? I have implemented some methods in `DRMailbox` which I want to share with my Akka actor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible, by design.  From [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/general/actors.html#mailbox):

> An important feature in which Akka differs from some other actor model
>   implementations is that the current behavior must always handle the
>   next dequeued message, there is no scanning the mailbox for the next
>   matching one. Failure to handle a message will typically be treated as
>   a failure, unless this behavior is overridden.

If you are really trying to access the mailbox from within an `Actor` then this suggests that you may be misusing the Actor pattern and should reconsider your design...